# Facing difficulty while sending mp3 file from Android to Server

Tags: android, androidhttpclient, loopj

I'am trying to send a mp3 file from my Android application to Server. I'am using this method [android async http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to send mp3 file.

This is my code.

```
            try {
                params1.put("file", new ByteArrayInputStream(MeetingFragment.mediafile));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            AsyncClientHandler.post("events/Uploadrecording/5", params1,
                    new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int statusCode,
                                Throwable error, String content) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            super.onFailure(statusCode, error, content);
                            Log.i("filename",myFile.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(_context, "failiure push"+ProjectEventFragment.event.eve_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int statusCode,
                                Header[] headers, String content) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, content);
                            Toast.makeText(_context, "success push"+ProjectEventFragment.event.eve_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i("Successpush",content.toString());
                        }                   

                    });
```

I have given the correct URL and i also getting value for the file. But it is going to success part. Could anyone help me to solve this problem? If you know any alternate way then please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

```
public static byte[] mediafile;
public static String record_file=null
 myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
      myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
      myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
      myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
      myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(record_file);
      mediafile = record_file.getBytes();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java Class**

```
class UpLoadFiles extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading profile ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Profile JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String sourceFileUri = "/mnt/sdcard/a.mp3";
    System.out.println("file path:" + sourceFileUri);

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
        ////System.out.println("file exists:" + sourceFile + " Email " + email);

        try {
            String upLoadServerUri ="http:/pairdroid.com/fileupload.php?";
            String filenameArray[] = sourceFile.getName().split("\\.");
            String extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length - 1];

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("bill", sourceFileUri);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bill\";filename=\""
                    + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file
            // data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                ////System.out.println("Uploaded http: 200//");

                // messageText.setText(msg);
                // Toast.makeText(ctx, "File Upload Complete.",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // recursiveDelete(mDirectory1);

            }

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        // dialog.dismiss();
        return "Executed";

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    }

}
```

php code(fileupload.php)

```
 <?php
  $uploads_dir = './';
  $tmp_name = $_FILES['bill']['tmp_name'];
  $pic_name = $_FILES['bill']['name'];

  if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$pic_name )) {
  }           
 ?>
```

Comment: I went to success part with my above code. I tried to check my sent file. It gives me some number with null value. (example - 14145345-null). I just did audio recording and assigned to String variable and again i converted to byte array. I have modified my question. Please check it.