# Android : How to send mp3 file as a metadata

Tags: android, metadata

I want to send mp3 file from android to server. But it goes only like a String. Even I did type caste to byte array. But it will give some number with null value(example - 14145444575-null). I don't know how to send this mp3 file as a metadata. Could someone give an example or guidance to me?

Comment: Sending an mp3 file as metadata? Please explain. The metadata of what?

Comment: @greenapps metadata of mp3file

Comment: So you want to send your mp3 file as metadata of your mp3 file? How would that go? This is nonsense.

Comment: @greenapps Could you please check this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672699/facing-difficulty-while-sending-mp3-file-from-android-to-server/26672861#26672861">post

Comment: Check for what? Please react on my comment first.